# Initiate save as > PDF using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been using a script that allows me to email a specific schedule in PDF format. In most cases, I just really want to download it. I could use Save as >> download as PDF. However, some of the sheets are hidden and I'd like to keep them that way as they clutter up the workbook. So, I've added a command to unhide the sheet, email as PDF and then hide the sheet. (i've removed it in the example below)
Is there any simple way to initiate the save as >> Download as PDF command by making a small change to the existing script i've been using?

Thanks in advance

```
function printschedule(WhichSheet) {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var objToSheetName = {"1":"Schedule 1","2":"Schedule 2","3":"Schedule 3"};
var whichSheetToPDF = objToSheetName[WhichSheet];  

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var prompt = ui.prompt('Send to which Email Address?');
 var email = prompt.getResponseText();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(whichSheetToPDF));
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


var subject = "Schedules"; 
var body = "";
var url =    
"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID",   ss.getId());
 var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
 + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
 + '&portrait=true'                    // orientation, false for landscape
 + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for    actual size
 + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
 + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
 + '&fzr=true'                         //  repeat row headers (frozen rows)   on each page
 + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext +    sheet.getSheetId()).getBlob().setName('Namexyz');

 if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    attachments:response,
   });

};
```